# Pyodbc script randomly zsh: abort when exicuting query on filemaker server

Tags: python, pyodbc, filemaker

I have been having a lot of issues connecting pyodbc to filemaker with my M1 Mac Mini.

I have finally sussed out that one of the reasons it took so long to figure out was that executing the query often causes the application to abort.

python script:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={FileMaker ODBC}...(rest of connection string)...encoding='iso-8859-1'")
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='iso-8859-1')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='iso-8859-1')
conn.setencoding(encoding='iso-8859-1')
query = "SELECT Code FROM Barcodes"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cur = cursor.execute(query)
```

half the time it gives me the data I requested and the rest of the time it gives me this error and aborts the script

```
Python(4742,0x202770e00) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fbd4acf9010: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x0
Python(4742,0x202770e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      python filemaker.py
```

help!

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug in the ODBC driver.